# What does a DisplayPort with arrow symbol (DP→) mean?

Tags: display, displayport

On a computer monitor, what does a "DP→" symbol mean?

e.g. a monitor has HDMI, DisplayPort, and USB sockets.  There's also a second Display Port socket labeled with "DP" and a right facing arrow.  What is that

Comment: I would check the manual for the monitor (or would if you posted the model), but I am guessing that tha is displayport OUT. You can chain multiple monitors that way with computer DP out -> Monitor 1 DP in.  Monitor 1 DP out -> Monitor 2 DP in and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it's a port for an "active cable".

[image]

- For these types of cables, the DisplayPort device can provide power to the cable.
- The primary benefit seems to be that this enables the cable to be much longer and also use thinner wires/be more flexible.

Here's an excerpt from the referenced Engadget article:

> Active cables boost and equalize the attenuated DisplayPort signal,
> allowing cables to reach unprecedented lengths and enabling the use of
> thinner wire gauges when compared to normal passive cables

and one from the referenced electronicdesign.com article:

> To solve the problem of long cables, one can create “active cables,”
> which incorporate a signal-conditioning silicon chip into the cable
> connector.

- Active cables are unidirectional, so the correct end must be connected to the source (video output) and sink (monitor).
- Note that searching for "active DisplayPort cable" will turn up many "active" adapters that convert from DVI, VGA, etc. to DisplayPort.  These aren't the same type of cable.

References:

- [Engadget Article, 2011](https://www.engadget.com/2011-06-22-displayport-1-2-adds-active-cable-support-brings-longer-cords.html)
- [Electronic Design Article, 2012](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/displays/article/21794830/active-displayport-cables-extend-videointerconnect-reach)
- [VESA DisplayPort Marketing Guidelines, 2013](https://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/DisplayPort-Marketing-Guidelines-v1_1.pdf) (slide 19)